# Sets and accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I need to find 3 countably infinite sets in $\mathbb R$ such that

$(a)$ every point of R is an accumulation point

$(b)$ The set has infinitely many accumulation points, none of which are in the set

$(c)$ the set has infinitely many accumulation points all of which are  in the set

Comment: There isn't any set that respects all three conditions.

Comment: @GitGud Not true. There is an obvious countable set that satisfies all three conditions. Condition b) is phrased awkwardly. What is meant is "there are infinitely many points not in the set that are accumulation points of the set".

Comment: @GitGud: As I read the question, it’s calling for three different sets, one satisfying (a), one satisfying (b), and one satisfying (c).

Comment: @Andrés: I think that (b) means exactly what it says: the set has infinitely many accumulation points, and they’re all in the complement of the set.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo In addition to concurring with BrianM.Scott, I read (a),(b) and (b),(c) as mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'll try to be clearer. I need 3 separate sets one that satisfies a) one b) and one for c)

and what Andres thinks about b is correct.

Comment: @Brandon No, it is not. :-) The interesting version is then the one you explicitly have. Sorry for misunderstanding at first.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: There is a really obvious answer to (a). For (b) and (c) you could start by thinking about translates of the set $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.